# Order of growth for loops

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What would be the order of growth of the code below. My guess was, each loop's growth is linear but the if statement is confusing me. How do I include that with the whole thing. I would very much appreciate an explanatory answer so I can understand the process involved.

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
for (int j = i+1; j < N; j++)
for (int k = j+1; k < N; k++)
if(a[i] + a[j] + a[k] == 0)
count++;
```

Comment: (The (lack of) comments & indentation of the code lines leaves doubt about what this is supposed to do.) Please be explicit about `[guess] each loop's growth is linear`. What _is_ your question? You have one statement the cost of which can be considered constant, as its control. This is in a triply nested loop: What if all loops ran from 0 to N? What in case of the initial values from above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things that can be confusing when trying to determine the code's complexity.

1. The fact that not all loops start from 0. The second loop starts from `i + 1` and the third from `j + 1`. Does this affect the complexity? It does not. Let's consider only the first two loops. For `i = 0`, the second runs `N - 1` times, for `i = 1` it runs `N - 2` times, ..., for `i = N - 1` it runs `0` times. Add all these up:

   ```
   0 + 1 + ... + N - 1 = N(N - 1) / 2 = O(N^2).
   ```

   So not starting from 0 does not affect the complexity (remember that big-oh ignores lower-order terms and constants). Therefore, even under this setting, the entire thing is `O(N^3)`.
2. The `if` statement. The `if` statement is clearly irrelevant here, because it's only part of the last loop and contains no `break` statement or other code that would affect the loops. It only affects the incrementation of a count, not the execution of any of the loops, so we can safely ignore it. Even if the count isn't incremented (an `O(1)` operation), the `if` condition is checked (also an `O(1)` operation), so the same rough number of operations is performed with and without the `if`.

   Therefore, even with the `if` statement, the algorithm is still `O(N^3)`.

Comment: Can I ask why you have divided N(N-1) by 2.

Comment: @JVTura - because the sum is calculated by grouping the first term with the last, the second with the second to last etc. for `0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4` for example, we would group `(0 + 4) + (1 + 3) + (2 + 2) + (3 + 1) + (4 + 0)`. There are `N = 5` groups, each with sum `N - 1 = 4`. But we have to divide by 2 because each group occurs twice, so we oversum if we do not divide: `5*4 / 2 = 10`, which is correct.

Comment: What would be the order of growth of this code snippet? `int sum =0; for(int n = N; n > 0; n/= 2;) for(int i = 0; i < n; i++;) sum++;`

Answer (score 2):

Order of growth of the code would be O(N^3).

In general k nested loops of length N contribute growth of O(N^k).

Comment: Does the fact that the nested loops shrink each iteration affect the outcome? I was expecting factorials or other modifier

Comment: Not really. While it would affect the constant next to N^k it doesn't really affect the O notation.

Comment: Maybe I went wrong then, still new to this: O(n * (n - 1) * (n-2)) = O(n^3 - 3*n^2 + 2n)

Comment: You are absolutely right! Note that O(n^3 - 3*n^2 + 2n) = O(n^3) since the largest "factor" always overtakes.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two was to find that the time complexity is Theta(N^3) without much calculation.

First, you select `i<j<k` from the range 0 through N-1. The number of ways to choose 3 objects out of N is the [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) N choose 3 = `N*(N-1)*(N-2)/(3*2*1) ~ (N^3)/6 = O(N^3)`, and more precisely Theta(N^3).

Second, an upper bound is that you choose i, j, and k from N possibilities, so there are at most `N*N*N = N^3` choices. This is O(N^3). You can also find a lower bound of the same type since you can choose i from 0 through N/3-1, j from N/3 through 2N/3-1, and k from 2N/3 through N-1. This gives you at least floor(N/3)^3 choices, which is about N^3/27. Since you have an upper bound and lower bound of the same form, the time complexity is Theta(N^3).